# While doing delete operation few fields are not audited its take value as null while persisting in db

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jboss, hibernate-envers

Using **Hibernate Envers**, while doing create operation audit functionality is properly working data is correctly filled up in main as well as audit table but   while **deleting** an entry for few fields  its taking null following is the code sample:

```
@Audited
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class A implements Serializable
{
private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;
@NotNull
private Long                id;
@NotNull
private String              user;   
private Timestamp           time;
}

@Entity
@Audited
public class B extends A
{
private static final long               serialVersionUID    = 1L;

@EmbeddedId
private EmbeddedId  embeddedId;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "CODE")
private Code                    code;
}

@Audited
@Embeddable
public class EmbeddedId implements Serializable
{
private static final long                   serialVersionUID    = 1L;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "C")
private C                       c;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumns(value =
{ @JoinColumn(name = "C_ID", referencedColumnName = "C_ID"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "D_ID", referencedColumnName = "D_ID") })
private D   d;

}   

@Entity
@Audited
public class Code extends A
{
private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long                cId;

private String              name;
}
```

**All the classes are annotated with @Audited**, when delete operation is fired Class B data is not properly getting audited. Data corresponding to the embeddedId (composite primary key) is reflecting in audit table but other data like (code, id, user, time) i.e member variable of that class as well as coming from inheritance are going as null in audit table.

Please provide with the detailed solution for this issue as i am new to Envers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want non-identifier attributes to be stored when you perform a `DELETE` operation, you must explicitly tell Envers that you wish to enable this behavior because by default it doesn't do that.

Simply toggle the configuration `org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete` to `true` and Envers will begin to capture and store the non-identifier audited attributes during the `DELETE` database operation.

You set this configuration where you supply other hibernate configuration properties.

Comment: thanks, now while performing Delete operation also, i am able to store the data into the database.but what exactly it means non-identifier attribute ??

Comment: Envers inherently stores the `@Id` or `@EmbeddedId` properties from your class when you create any type of revision (insert, update, or delete); however, it normally only stores the other audited attributes when you perform an insert or update only.  By setting this property, you cause Envers to store all audited attributes of your entity class and related classes when you perform a deletion of an audited entity class.

Answer (score 2):

Just a minor addition:
In our environment using spring boot and Hibernate - the following variable made the trick (since the one offered here dod not - but gave me the idea about how to address it):

**spring.jpa.properties**.org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete=true